# MySQL: Nested SQL using IN

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a SQL that looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE foo.bar IN (SELECT foobar.bar FROM foobar)
```

This is not good, right? The nested SELECT will cause things to slow down? How should I query something like this?

Comment: The nested SQL is not dependent though. You could look at LEFT JOIN and filter NULL records of the right hand columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IN clause is perfectly valid SQL, but it's not always the preferred way. I've often found that MySQL's performance on them is pretty poor, even if `foo.bar` is indexed.

If you change it to a join, you have to be careful if the second table has multiple rows that match the join condition for each row of the first table, because the join will produce multiple result rows.  If this is possible, the join should be:

```
SELECT f.*
FROM foo f
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT bar FROM foobar) fb USING (bar);
```

The ultimate answer is that you should use EXPLAIN to see how different forms of the query will be executed. But if you're not experiencing a performance problem in the first place, don't sweat it.

If you want all the rows where `f.bar` does *not* exist in `foobar`, `NOT IN` is usually the most succinct way to write it. But it can also be written using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT f.*
FROM foo f
LEFT OUTER JOIN foobar fb USING (bar)
WHERE fb.bar IS NULL
```

You don't need the subquery in this case because you're only reporting the non-matching rows, so there obviously can't be multiple matches in the result.

Comment: I'd probably switch it to `SELECT DISTINCT f.* FROM foo f JOIN foobar fb USING(bar)` to make it a little easier to read. No nested query that way.

Comment: And what if I wanted to all records from `foo` where `foo.bar` does not exist in `foobar.bar`?

Answer (score 0):

You can also rewrite this as

```
Select
  * 
From
  foo f
Where
  Exists ( -- If you want the opposite, put Not in front here
    Select 'x'
    From foobar fb
    Where f.bar = fb.bar
  );
```

Over the years, different DBMS's have dealt better with the query in one of the different forms, even though they are all equivalent. Most that I've tried can generate the same plan for both now. Not something I've tried on mysql, though.